# In WinForms, how can I create a delete button in a DevExpress GridControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I'm trying to create a delete button at the right of every row in a DevExpress GridControl, like this:

[image]

What I've done is added another column and set its ColumnEdit property to an instance of RepositoryItemButtonEdit.  I handle the ButtonClick event, to delete a row.

I can determine which row I'm on from this code:

```
myGridView.GetRow(myGridView.FocusedRowHandle);
```

Because I don't want a text editor on my button, I set the TextEditStyle to HideTextEditor.

By default, the button shows an ellipsis.

To remove the ellipsis, I adjusted the Buttons property on the RepositoryItemButtonEdit.  I set the Kind to Glyph and set the image to my X icon.

Unfortunately that seems to simply remove the button altogether.

Does anyone know a better way to do this, or a way to show a button with an image on it, in each grid row?

Comment: For a simple task like this, DevExpress is a mess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that there is actually a delete button kind.  So, I do everything as in the question, but instead of choosing the kind Glyph, I choose Delete, and I don't need to select an image.

Answer (score 3):

I have summarized what I found in the [DevExpress forum](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/72394/246853.aspx):

Use the `ButtonEdit`  control and set the `TextEditStyle` property to `HideTextEditor`. The Repository Item has a `Buttons` collection through which you can add a caption, image etc.

In the `Buttons` collection, change the "Kind" property to "Glyph".
You can use the `CustomRowCellEdit` event to conditionally apply editors on a cell-by-cell basis.
Make sure you set the Button's `Kind` property to "Glyph" and set the `Caption` property to whatever text you'd like:

```
DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemButtonEdit buttonEdit = 
    new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemButtonEdit();
buttonEdit.Buttons[0].Kind = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Glyph;
buttonEdit.Buttons[0].Caption = "X";
buttonEdit.TextEditStyle =             
    DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.HideTextEditor;
e.RepositoryItem = buttonEdit;
```

You should handle the GridView's `CustomRowCellEdit` event, construct a new `RepositoryItemButtonEdit` and assign it to the `e.RepositoryItem property`.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Yes, that works.  Thank you for that - I've marked your answer as useful.  A couple of comments: 1. One just needs to wrap your code in if(e.Column == [DeleteColumnName]) {...}, otherwise it turns all the columns into buttons.  2. I prefer my answer (using the Delete kind instead of Glyph) because I think using the built in X is tidier than typing "X".  I still haven't figured out how to use a custom image for the X, but it doesn't really matter.